# Best way to define Java constant dates

Tags: java, date, calendar, constants

I want define some constants, specifically a Date and Calendar that are before my domain can exist. I've got some code that works but its ugly. I am looking for improvement suggestions.

    `static Calendar working;
    static {
        working = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        working.set(1776, 6, 4, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    public static final Calendar beforeFirstCalendar = working;
    public static final Date beforeFirstDate = working.getTime();`

I'm setting them to July 4th, 1776.
I'd rather not have the "working" variable at all.

Thanks

Comment: Note that making it `final` doesn't make it immutable. You might want to look at JodaTime instead, its `DateTime` is immutable and can safely be declared `final` as intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand....but doesn't this work?

```
public static final Calendar beforeFirstCalendar;
static {
    beforeFirstCalendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    beforeFirstCalendar.set(1776, 6, 4, 0, 0, 1);
}
public static final Date beforeFirstDate = beforeFirstCalendar.getTime();
```

Comment: You can even put the 1st line of the `static {}` back into the declaration to save one line of code: `public static final Calendar beforeFirstCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();` It's namely not an immutable class, you can still edit it everywhere (and the `final` changes really nothing in that regard).

Answer (score 5):

I'd extract it to a method (in a util class, assuming other classes are going to want this as well):

```
class DateUtils {
  public static Date date(int year, int month, int date) {
    Calendar working = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    working.set(year, month, date, 0, 0, 1);
    return working.getTime();
  }
}
```

Then simply,

```
public static final Date beforeFirstDate = DateUtils.date(1776, 6, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be clearer to use the XML string notation. This is more human readable and also avoids the local variable which you wanted to eliminate:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

Date theDate = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("1776-06-04T00:00:00-05:00").getTime()
```